# Getting null(undefined) when using NgSelect with default value setting

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7, angular-ngselect

I need to use the NgSelect drop down for PO. And I used the below codes.

**TS**

In .ts file I declare the form Group as below,

```
  createForm() {
    this.poFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      purchaseOrderId: ['0',[]],
   });
  }
```

I should pass the default value in purchaseOrderId.

I get the value using the below method,

```
  getAllPurchaseOrders() {
    this.purchaseOrderService.getAllPurchaseOrders().subscribe(
    data => {
       this.purchaseOrder = data;
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
    <ng-select [items]="purchaseOrder" bindLabel="referenceNumber"
    bindValue="id" placeholder="Select PO" clearAllText="Clear" 
    formControlName="purchaseOrderId>

        <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
           <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{item.purchaseOrderStatusName }}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
         <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{item.purchaseOrderStatusName}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
```

Now in UI , the dropdown seems like below.

[image]

While searching, I got the answer to solve this problem is passing null value in form group declaration.Like below

```
purchaseOrderId: [null,[]]
```

But I cant use this method. Because I have to pass the default value
purchaseOrderId: ['0',[]]

Is there any other method to solve this problem?

Comment: Can anybody help me??

Comment: Can you do a snippet on stackblitz.com demonstrating your error ? It will be easier to spot the error

Comment: are you sure the purchaseOrder getting the value before the page loads ?

Comment: can you show how your data looks?

Comment: yes, getting the values before the page loads. Options are listing correctly, but instead of placeholder "Select PO" , its displaying like null(undefined)

Comment: Actually my purchaseOrderId is in GUID format(some strings). For another concept I should set & pass the  default value  and  I used GUID default value '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' in it.

Comment: <ng-select [items]="purchaseOrder | async"> can you try it like this?

Comment: @Ramachandran. Not working